# why does Julia uses column major? is it fast

Tags: performance, matrix, julia

I have read many articles on julia and its performance. but no where, i can find clue about why julia team decided to use column major for matrix operations. is it because thier way of operating on matrix fits on column major or something.

Advance thanks.

Comment: Why does DNA spiral this way and not the other? The decision is mostly due to some historical symmetry breaking with a bit switching cost added

Comment: I really dont know about DNA. but yes in performance it worked more or less similar to C. so i felt there may be a reason why they chose column major rather then row major?

Comment: Most calculations can be rewritten with all variables transposed. This would turn rows into columns. The chosen order makes multiplying by a vector on one side faster than on the other and once you make the choice, you should propagate the choice to all the rest of the calculations in your algorithms. Specifically, multiplying `w*A` is slower than `A*v`. So there is the answer: people prefer `A*v`

Comment: It is a bit more convenient for linear algebra, and it inherits this from Matlab, which is the most obvious place to look for inspiration for user-friendly linalg. Also, you must choose _some_ dimension, and isn't it more natural to choose the _first_ dimension rather than the _second_? Why not the third, or the last. Having the second dimension being fastest has always struck me as particularly strange and arbitrary.

Comment: Probably because most numeric libraries were originally written in Fortran, which uses column-major storage, which then mimics the fact that vectors in math are by convention columns. Same applies to Matlab, which started as a convenient way to speak to some Fortran linear algebra packages.

Comment: thank you @HristoIliev and DNF but also C shows same performance but its row major. it may be a convention. but i always thought may be a large linear array on 2nd dimension is easier to operate, rather then on fpicking first dimension which is large and operating on small array. pardon me if i am wrong.

Comment: No, it's not that column major is faster or slower than row major. It is a choice of whether you want fast column operations or fast row operations. One is not inherently faster than the other.

Comment: I know this is severe nitpicking, but no, C is _not_ "row major" as such by design, this is simply a consequence of how one creates a multidimensional array in memory. For a three-dimensional array, e.g., the innermost dimension will be the one contiguous in memory, not the 2nd. Whereas scientific programming languages which are designed with array / vectorized programming in mind tend to make an explicit decision on how to represent such arrays in memory. Most scientific programming languages choose 'vector' representation as stated above. Python is an exception, mostly as historical accident

Comment: @dan left-handed DNA is structurally and physically different than the far more predominant right-handed   http://www.nytimes.com/library/national/science/062999sci-genome-zdna.html

Comment: It was a mistake. So was dropping dimension reduction for aggregators like `sum`. They should have studied numpy harder. So much was done right that these things are sad.

Answer (score 2):

"Multidimensional arrays in Julia are stored in column-major order. This means that arrays are stacked one column at a time. This can be verified using the vec function or the syntax [:] ..."

"This convention for ordering arrays is common in many languages like Fortran, Matlab, and R (to name a few). The alternative to column-major ordering is row-major ordering, which is the convention adopted by C and Python (numpy) among other languages."

For examples and discussion of performance differences, see the [Performance Tips](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/performance-tips/#man-performance-column-major) section of Julia's Manual.

Comment: from the link: "Arrays are stored contiguously in memory, lending themselves to CPU vectorization and fewer memory accesses due to caching. These are the same reasons that it is recommended to access arrays in column-major order (see above)."